Is it possible to go from art school to a graduate school in mathematics?
Is it possible to go from art school to a graduate school in mathematics?
I am currently a 21-year-old university student. I studied for two years at a university of science and technology, but the level of the university was not high, and I could not master discrete geometry and graph theory, which I wanted to master, because they were mainly engineering mathematics. I decided that I could not do advanced research at the graduate school of this university based on my professor's words, "Advanced research is not possible at our graduate school.
I withdrew from the university and enrolled in a correspondence course college in April of this year as a means of entering my ideal graduate school, but the content was completely different from the level of mathematics I was looking for (e.g., it only dealt with elementary algebra). Therefore, I am considering dropping out of this university as soon as possible.
I have always been interested in Western art and computer illustration as well as mathematics, and I was planning to take painting classes at the same time after being accepted to graduate school, but after receiving this offer, I decided to spend my bachelor's degree in computer illustration rather than studying at a boring university. And at the same time, I plan to attend a math tutoring school, and in the future, with the support of an instructor with a graduate degree in mathematics, I plan to enter graduate school in mathematics and become either a university professor or a (web) designer who uses discrete mathematics such as combinatorics.
All in all, am I making a reckless choice? I want to at least go to grad school, so I need advice on three main points.
1,as someone with a background in mathematics, is it difficult to go from art school to graduate school in mathematics?
2,are there any other professions that use discrete mathematics other than the ones I mentioned?
3,how much would it affect my career if I dropped out of my current university?
Any other advice would be appreciated.

Have you had courses in advanced analysis, abstract algebra, and topology?

This question is similar to: Path from humanities undergrad to math PhD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Welcome to the site. Check out similar questions and answers such as the one I tagged.

In what country or countries do you hope to study math at the graduate level?

Regarding your first question, each grad school will have its own policies, but I would say that, at any of them, it will be much harder to get into grad school with an art degree rather than a math degree. Also, if you are already interested in grad school in math, there seems to be little reason to pursue a different undergraduate degree. However, if you are specifically interested in some combination of math and art, you might find a grad program that fits and, in that case, you should tailor your undergrad work to match their requirements.
Taking additional classes while pursuing a graduate degree seems very ambitious. Most grad students are more than busy, just with their studies (and other duties at the university).  There are common complaints about not having enough time to eat, sleep, and so on. Still, some people can do it.
I don't think "math tutoring school" is likely to be a substitute for an undergraduate degree.

Going straight to a PhD program is both not likely to be possible and even if it is, is unlikely to succeed. But many Masters programs at smaller schools which don't have PhDs are setup specifically to transition for people with either poor grades or non-standard backgrounds to be able to then do a PhD in math. Take a look at those.

How to locate these programs you described? Is there a procedure one can follow?

@hym3242 I don't know of any specific procedure, but most Masters in the US will work decently for this. If you are uncertain about a specific program, you can also ask them if this is something they aim for.
